# Picard's theorem analogue for difference equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations

I am trying find bibliography on existence of solutions for difference equations but it seems that there is not much on the web.

I need existence and bound of a certain nonlinear difference equation of the form $$x(t+1)=a\, x(t)+f(x(t))$$
With $f$ analytic without constant or linear terms. I am searching for an analytic solution by the way.

So I have a couple of questions. Can I rearrange it somehow to get existence by fixed point theorem? Basically is there an analogue of Picard's theorem?

If I can majorate $f$ with some $F$ and I can solve
$$X(t+1)=a\, X(t)+F(X(t))$$
then do I get any information about the solution $x(t)$?

Also with which classes of $F$ can I hope to actually solve the above equation?

Any ideas are kindly welcomed.

Comment: Your use of the word "difference equation" suggests that $t$ is an integer-valued variable. In that case, existence is trivial: just use the equation to successively compute $x(t+1)$ from $x(t)$. And what do you mean by an "analytic" solution?

Comment: Ah, no. I look at this as a functional equation and that is why I write $x(t)$. I expect that if $f$ is analytic then there is an analytic solution for the equations (at least to some domain). You can think of it as the Gamma function which is an analytic function that satisfies $\Gamma(t+1)=t\,\Gamma(t)$. I understand that this is not unique but I am wondering whether I can get existence and some bound somehow.